# Differentiability of $a^x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

I'm sure almost anyone who registered at this forum, knows that $\frac{d(a^x)}{dx} = a^x\ln a \quad $ for $a>0$

But what if you want to actually prove this identity? I'd come along an interesting problem in a standard textbook on calculus where the author asks, "*Suppose* $f(x)=a^x$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and that $f'(0)=k$ where $k\neq 0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at any real number $x$ and that $f'(x)=k\,a^x = k f(x).$", which is no big deal (using definition of differentiation). But I became curious that,

How can one deduce that the differentiation of the function at the $0$ is bounded and equal to $\ln a$?

Any help on approaching this problem would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of $a^x?$

Comment: $a$ to be positive real base to the power x as an independent variable

Comment: That's not a definition. For example what would $2^\pi$ be?

Comment: @zhw. Ahhh, in the questions thou shalt see the path!!! :-) I know what you're trying to do (Neo to Morpheus), but if we only define exponential functions of $f(x)=a^x$ to be defined only for rational numbers (roots and powers are only meaningful in the language of zahlens), then beautiful properties like connectivity (holes appear) and compactness (for example let $f$ be defined on $[-\pi,e]$ which by Heine-Borel thrm is compact) are going to be withdrawn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $a^x$ at $x=0$ is
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h}. $$
This is one way of defining $\log{a}$, but of course you then have the problem of defining $a^x$.

If we instead define $\log$, at least initially, as the inverse of the exponential, and then define the general power function as $a^x=e^{x\log{a}}$, the result follows from the chain rule, or using the power series for the exponential.

Alternatively, if one defines the logarithm using an integral, we can obtain the result by exchanging the limit and integral (which is fine because the power functions converge uniformly on the compact interval $[1,a]$):
$$ \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \int_1^a x^{h-1} \, dx \to \int_1^a x^{-1}\, dx = \log{a} $$
as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Hmmm, so you just carry the author's assumption from "knowing the differentiability of $f$ at zero" to "knowing the integrability of $x^-1$"?

Comment: The method of proof of identities like this depend on the definitions one uses. I have given three alternatives, depending on three common definitions of the logarithm; which of these definitions is used also determines what can be said about $a^x$ (which is sometimes consigned to hastily to the "obvious" bin). But from a pedagogic point of view I would certainly rather that students acquire the impression that integrability is a more robust initial assumption that differentiability.

Answer (score 3):

This is the chain rule, you note merely that $a^x = e^{x\log a}$. So $u(x) = x\log a$ and then you take derivatives and you get

$${d\over dx}e^u = {d\over du}e^u\cdot {du\over dx}$$

$u$ is a linear function, so the derivative is just the slope, $\log a$ which gives you

$$e^u(\log a) = e^{x\log a}\log a=a^x\log a.$$

But in particular the chain rule tells you this holds at $x=0$ since ${d\over du}e^u$ exists at $u(0)$ and ${d\over dx}(x\log a)$ exists at $0$.